# CSS not linking in html

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

I am trying to change background color of a web page.
To do so I am linking *style.css* externally to *index.html* using href:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media=”screen”/> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- body of...body -->
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS is simply:

```
body
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

My project structure is:

[image]

Note *index.html* resides by itself on the project folder (freebookz), whereas *style.css* resides in a dedicated folder (css). Hence the reason for

```
href="css/style.css"
```

The problem is that the CSS is not linking.
I'm using Vscode and I've also tried replicating this project in Notepad++ and CSS still does not work.
I've tried force-reloading the page with **SHIFT+CTRL+R** to no avail.

Can someone point me to the error?
I've exhausted all attempts to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello this is paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your  tag check your media attribute, instead of double quotation mark, you have used this `Unicode character “”” (U+201D)` .

Here is my code, paste it in your code, it would work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen"/>
```

Let me know whether it is working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, have you tried uncommenting it?
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media=”screen”/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- body of...body -->
    </body>
</html>
```